# How to execute function in iOS when app is installing on device

Tags: swift

I have a pretty large text file that I have to read and store all values in a database. I'm wondering if there is any way to run a function when the user downloads the app from the app store and the app is installed. My current solution is that the function will be executed only once when the app is executed the first time. But I would like to avoid the "wait a minute..." loading screen for the first time and outsource this procedure in the installing process. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you not copy a pre-cooked database from the bundle into the local file system? Why does the database need to be constructed on the device.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to preload the data into `Coredata` when the app launches for the first time.
To solve the waiting time, just execute the fetch request in a `backgroundContext()`. Try have a look at [this](https://medium.com/swift2go/fetching-remote-data-with-core-data-background-context-in-ios-app-224dad15ef6c) too implement this.

This ensures that your UI doesn't freezes and your app functions normally while the data are being loaded in a background thread.